# Limiting user to single app

Tags: django, permissions

I have a Django project with several apps. I'd like to restrict a particular user's access to only one specific app and at the time of the user's creation, i.e. without having to say modify every method of `views.py` with decorators such as `@permission_required`.

Is this possible? That is, is it possible to declare that user 'A' can only use app 'X' without modifying any of app 'Y's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write some middleware that implements the [`process_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) method, then check which app the view function belongs to.

For example, this is one (potentially buggy) way you could do it:

```
class RestrictAppMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, *args, **kwargs):
        view_module = view_func.__module__
        allowed_apps = apps_visible_to_user(request.user)
        if not any(app_name in view_module for app_name in allowed_apps):
            return HttpResponse("Not authorized", status=403)
```

Obviously you'd need to improve on the heuristic (ex, this one will allow users with access too "foo" view "foobar" as well) and consider apps which rely on Django built-in views (ex, `direct_to_template`)… But this is the way I'd do it.